# Issues with setVisibility on ImageButtons

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

Hey so I've been searching around for this topic and couldn't find a whole lot so I think I'm in the clear to ask this. What I want to accomplish is have two image buttons that are overlapping in an XML layout. Then in the .java file when the top button is clicked it dissapears and the second image button appears. When that is clicked it dissapears and the first image button reappears and on and on.

The problem I'm having is when i click the first button it dissapears fine and works for a total of two times around then everything dissapears. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right and there might be a better way to accomplish this than how i'm doing it so I will happily take advice.

Also, the reason i don't have another line in the fist button that sets musicbutton2 as visible is because when I do that the label highlights in blue and it causes a force close.

optionsActivity.java (New):

```
    package com.crazycastles;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class optionsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageButton musicbutton, musicbutton2;
    boolean answer=true;
    final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(
            optionsActivity.this, R.raw.swords);


    @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.options);




          if (answer=true){  
            //CREATE BUTTON 1 & SOUND
            final ImageButton musicbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.musicbutton);
            musicbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                musicbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.musicbutton2);
                buttonSound.start();
                answer=false;
            }
            });
          }


          if (answer!=true){  
                //CREATE BUTTON 1 & SOUND
                final ImageButton musicbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.musicbutton);
                musicbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    musicbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.musicbutton);
                    buttonSound.start();
                    answer=true;
                }
                });
              }




}
}
```

options.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mainscreen" >

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/musicbutton"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/musicbutton"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems are coming because of the way you are trying to use the linear layout and the margin top to scoot one of the buttons up.

Check out [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) if you switch to using one of those as your parent then you can get rid of the margin stuff. The buttons will default to being overlapped like you are aiming for. If you do that and are still getting the same problem then add some Log debugging statments to your click listeners that output when the buttons are changing visibility to try to see what is happening.

If your aim is simply to make the way the button looks change I would recommend only using one button and just changing its background with [Button.setBackgroundResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29). You can just keep a boolean flag and use it check whether you should set to R.drawable.musicbutton or R.drawable.musicbutton2

Comment: If I used only one button and only changed the appearance would I still be able to have it do two different actions like pause and resume music for example?

Comment: yes, you just keep a boolean flag that you can check with an if statment. And each time it is pressed you flip the boolean. Inside your if statment you can do whatever you like for each possibility.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with this. I'm pretty new to everything and am not sure where to go from here. I updated my activity class up above. Thanks